# Check if the sub set of numbers is in starting part of the series or bottom part of the series using jQuery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example: I have set 1,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,11

1. scenario 1 : subset = 1,3,4 which is in starting part of the series = **Acceptable**
2. scenario 2 : subset = 8,10,11 which is in ending part of the series = **Acceptable**
3. scenario 3 : subset = 1,3,10,11 which is in both starting and ending part of the series = **Acceptable**
4. scenario 4 : subset = 1,3,6,8 which is in starting part of series and also in the middle of the series = **Not Acceptable**.

Main thing to achieve is to check if the given series is in starting part of the series or ending part without breaking the series using jquery or javacript

Help will be much appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are the numbers in the set always ordered?

Comment: tried using arrays with single number in series at start or ending but need help to check this with sub set

Comment: no they are not ordered @Apfelbox

Comment: where is your code share it

Comment: its paper work @Bhargav

Comment: which type of output you need

Comment: Boolean **true** or **false** will do ( which mean accepted or not accepted)

Comment: btw, why jquery?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a two pass approach, with first collecting for all subarray items the comparison at the same index from start and end (later denoted as left and right side).

To indicate a result, 4 states are returned which mean

- `0` - no match, neither from the left nor from the right side matches the value,
- `1` - item of the left side of the array matches,
- `2` - item of the right side of the array matches,
- `3` - item matches on both sides.

After collecting the values which represent match and position, the values have to be consolidated to the wanted result, `true` or `false`.

To check each value, you need another value which represents the expected side. At start, the expected side is set to `1`, because it starts at the left side to check.

The temporary result of the callback with [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) is a single check if the actual value is greater or equal to the expected value. This includes indicator `3` because this value is in both sides. A value of zero exits the loop as well.

If a value of `2` is found, then it indicates the right side and all following elements have to be greater than `2`, therefor the expected value is set to `2`.

The presented solution could be shortened to just return the wanted boolean value.

```js
function check(array, subarray) {
    var expected = 1,
        temp = subarray.map(function (a, i) {
            var offset = array.length - subarray.length;
            return (a === array[i]) + 2 * (a === array[i + offset]);
        }),
        result = temp.every(function (a) {
            var r = a >= expected;
            if (a === 2) {
                expected = 2;
            }
            return r;
        });
    return temp.concat(result);
}

var array = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11];

console.log(check(array, [1, 3, 4]));      // true
console.log(check(array, [8, 10, 11]));    // true
console.log(check(array, [1, 3, 10, 11])); // true
console.log(check(array, [1, 3, 6, 8]));   // false
console.log(check([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 4, 3, 6]));   // false
console.log(check([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 4, 3, 6]));   // false
console.log(check([1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4], [3, 2, 3, 2]));   // false
console.log(check([1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]));   // true
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

The short version without a temporary array.

```js
function check(array, subarray) {
    var offset = array.length - subarray.length,
        expected = 1;

    return subarray.every(function (a, i) {
        var state = (a === array[i]) + 2 * (a === array[i + offset]),
            result = state >= expected;
        if (state === 2) {
            expected = 2;
        }
        return result;
    });
}

var array = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11];

console.log(check(array, [1, 3, 4]));      // true
console.log(check(array, [8, 10, 11]));    // true
console.log(check(array, [1, 3, 10, 11])); // true
console.log(check(array, [1, 3, 6, 8]));   // false
console.log(check([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 4, 3, 6]));   // false
console.log(check([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 4, 3, 6]));   // false
console.log(check([1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4], [3, 2, 3, 2]));   // false
console.log(check([1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]));   // true
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple approach: remove matching numbers from the beginning and end of both arrays, and see if there are any leftovers.

```js
var checkIt = function(arr,subarr) {
  // strip off matching numbers at the beginning
  while (subarr.length && arr[0] === subarr[0]) {
    arr.shift();
    subarr.shift();
  }
  
  // strip off matching numbers at the end
  while (subarr.length && arr[arr.length - 1] === subarr[subarr.length - 1]) {
    arr.pop();
    subarr.pop();
  }
  
  // if there aren't any leftovers, return true
  return (subarr.length === 0)
}


console.log(checkIt( [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11],[1, 3, 4]));
console.log(checkIt( [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11],[8, 10, 11]));
console.log(checkIt( [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11],[1, 3, 10, 11]));
console.log(checkIt( [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11],[1, 3, 6, 8]));

// pathological edge case:
console.log(checkIt( [1,2,3,2,1],[1,2,3,2,1] ))
// This returns true, but based on the rules of the puzzle I'm honestly not sure whether that's correct.
```

Comment: +1. I think this is a clear way of expressing the solution.  It also doesn't make any assumptions about the ordering or types in the arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You would iterate through the subarray from left to right, and from right to left, and stop where the value does not match with the value in the main array at the "corresponding position", i.e. the position counting from the same side of the array.

If at the end of both loops all values of the subarray matched, i.e. the two indexes crossed each other, then the result is `true`.

Here is the code:

```js
function isSubsetAtEnds(array, subarray) {
    const diff = array.length - subarray.length;
    let i, j;
    if (diff < 0) return false;
    for (i = 0; i < subarray.length; i++)
        if (array[i] !== subarray[i]) break;
    for (j = subarray.length - 1; j >= i; j--)
        if (array[j+diff] !== subarray[j]) break;
    return j < i;
}

var array = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11];

console.log(isSubsetAtEnds(array, [1, 3, 4]));      // true
console.log(isSubsetAtEnds(array, [8, 10, 11]));    // true
console.log(isSubsetAtEnds(array, [1, 3, 10, 11])); // true
console.log(isSubsetAtEnds(array, [1, 3, 6, 8]));   // false
```